# JS - Create smart auto complete

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search, autocomplete

Given a sorted Array of Strings, and user input I need to return the most relevant result.

**Example**: Array =`['Apple','Banana and Melon','Orange']` and user input = `'Mellllon'` the returned value should be `'Banana and Melon'`

I'm looking for the right algorithm to implement an efficient auto complete solution, and **not an out of the box one**.

Comment: I would advise you to have a look at [Faster JavaScript fuzzy string matching function?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23905/105433)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Levenshtein distance** seems to be right for this problem. You need to calculate distance between every word in array, check it out

```
function findClosestString(arr, inputvalue) {
  let closestOne = "";
  let floorDistance = 0.1;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let dist = distance(arr[i], inputvalue);
    if (dist > floorDistance) {
        floorDistance = dist;
      closestOne = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return closestOne;
}

function distance(val1, val2) {
  let longer, shorter, longerlth, result;

  if (val1.length > val2.length) {
    longer = val1;
    shorter = val2;
  } else {
    longer = val2;
    shorter = val1;
  }

  longerlth = longer.length;

  result = ((longerlth - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / parseFloat(longerlth));

  return result;
}

function editDistance(val1, val2) {
  val1 = val1.toLowerCase();
  val2 = val2.toLowerCase();

  let costs = [];

  for(let i = 0; i <= val1.length; i++) {
    let lastVal = i;
    for(let j = 0; j <= val2.length; j++) {
        if (i === 0) {
        costs[j] = j;
      } else if (j > 0) {
        let newVal = costs[j - 1];
        if (val1.charAt(i - 1) !== val2.charAt(j - 1)) {
          newVal = Math.min(Math.min(newVal, lastVal), costs[j]) + 1;
        }
        costs[j - 1] = lastVal;
        lastVal = newVal;
      }
    }
    if (i > 0) { costs[val2.length] = lastVal }
  }

  return costs[val2.length];
}

findClosestString(['Apple','Banana and Melon','Orange'], 'Mellllon');
```

Comment: Super, that is what I looked for, here is a nice implementation for the getDistance method: https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to:

1) convert every value into some simple code (using the same simple rules e.g. convert uppercase char to lowercase, if a char is the same as the previews, it won't get written and so on..) so you have `['aple','banana and melon', 'orange']`

2) then you convert the user input , `Mellllon` => `melon`

3) now you can simple run

`return match_array.filter((x) => {
    x.indexOf(match_input)!=-1)
);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, as elaborately explained in [the topic cited in my comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/faster-javascript-fuzzy-string-matching-function/23905#23905) a fuzzy search regex might come handy provided you have all letters of the searched string (case insensitive "m", "e", "l", "o", "n") are present in the input string in the order of appearance. So according to the generated `/M[^e]*e[^l]*l[^o]*o[^n]*n/i` regexp from "Melon", "Maellion", "MElllloon" or "nMelrNnon" should all return `true`.

```js
function fuzzyMatch(s,p){
    p = p.split("").reduce((a,b) => a+'[^'+b+']*'+b);
    return RegExp(p,"i").test(s);
}

var arr = ['Apple','Banana and Melon','Orange'],
    inp = "MaellL;loin",
    res = arr.filter(s => s.split(" ").some(w => fuzzyMatch(inp,w)));
console.log(res);
```

Combining the `fuzzyMatch` function with a trie type data structure you might in fact obtain quite reasonable elastic auto complete functionality.